# How to resolve error 400 in excel-vba

Tags: excel, delete-row, vba

I am writing an excel-vba to find and delete entire row if having blanks cell in a particular column. My macro is working fine if there is at least one blank cell but showing error 400 if there is no blank cell. My code is

```
Sub GPF_Sign()
Dim i As Integer, n as integer
Dim LROW As Long

    LROW = Sheets("GPF").Range("B200").End(xlUp).Row

    n = Range("D9:D" & LROW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.Count
    If n > 0 Then
        Range("D9:D" & LROW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using B200 for LROW?

Comment: because my rows cannot exceed 150

Comment: you can use this instead of specifying a range value, `LROW = Sheets("GPF").Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @GowthamShiva - I think you meant `LROW = Sheets("GPF").Range("B" & Sheets("GPF").rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` (you forgot to qualify the `Rows` with the correct worksheet)

Comment: Why not Autofilter?

Comment: @YowE3K yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: just before n=....., add: dim rg as range: set rg=Range("D9:D" & LROW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) : if not rg is nothing then ..... you go with n=rg.cells.count , and so on.... the on error resume next is completly not needed and bad practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick

**Way 1: Using OERN (On Error Resume Next)**

```
Sub WAY_ONE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LROW As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("GPF")

    With ws
        LROW = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Range("D9:D" & LROW).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

**Way 2: Using Autofilter**

```
Sub WAY_TWO()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LROW As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("GPF")

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        LROW = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("D9:D" & LROW)

        With rng 'Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `On Error Resume Next`, but this is not a usually recommended approach because it may mask other errors. Instead, try computing `n` in an error free way:

```
n = Application.CountIf(Sheets("GPF").Range("D9:D" & LROW), "")
```

yet another, still better way is to use `AutoFilter`:

```
Sub GPF_Sign()
  With Sheets("GPF").Range("D8:D200")
    .AutoFilter 1, ""
    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ I would also go for Autofilter

Comment: BTW it should be `.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks. btw `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is not needed, because `.Delete` will take effect on the visible rows only :)

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using ".SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)" is attempting to return a range. If there are no blank cells, the next part ".cells.count" is attempting to count Nothing. That's why it gives you an error.

Since you are already checking if n>0, you could just add `On Error Resume Next` right above the "n= " line. If there is more code after this, you probably want to put a `On Error GoTo 0` after this part so it doesn't ignore later errors.

Comment: Alternatively, `LROW` must be greater than or equal to 9.